# jQuery how to put hash value in GET request parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, get

I send the get request as this way, and the goal is to download an excel file.

```
var filter = {
  'type': 'credit',
  'status': 'fail',
  'invoice_type': 'invoce',
}
var url = `/download_money_report?filter=${filter}`
window.location.assign(url);
```

But in the backend(Rails), I get the parameter like this 
`{ "filter" => "[object Object]" }`

How should I do to make it become

```
{ 
  "filter" => {
    "type" => 'credit',
    "status" => 'fail',
    "invoice_type" => 'invoce',
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to either encode the object as JSON in JS, send it in a single parameter then deserialise the JSON in your Ruby logic - or instead send each parameter individually in the querystring then create the object from those URL parameters in your Ruby code.

Comment: You can stringify the filter before adding it to the URL. As written, you just trigger the toString() function of an object with the shown result:
var url = `/download_money_report?filter=${JSON.stringify(filter)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `JSON.Stringify(filter)` before attaching it to the URL and parse back in the Rails

Answer (score 0):

You need convert an object to url, here is an example:

```
var filter = {
     'type': 'credit',
     'status': 'fail',
     'invoice_type': 'invoce',
};


var str = Object.keys(filter).map(function(key){ 
  return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]); 
}).join('&');

console.log(str); //"type=credit&status=fail&invoice_type=invoce"
var url = `/download_money_report?${str}`
=> "/download_money_report?type=credit&status=fail&invoice_type=invoce"
```

In Rails it would be:

```
params[:type] => credit
params[:status] => fail
params[:invoce_type] => invoce
```

Comment: @CodaChang sure, because you're using GET with body, that's _over-killed_.